# find a number that is not in the ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Table has two columns Name and ID.

```
ID (int,not null)
Name (nvarchar(255),not null)
```

I need a SQL script that will run on a report server that will do the following:

```
User inputs "New.Name"
User inputs "Old.Name"
```

If "New.Name" AND "Old.Name" is not in Column [Name] then Print "Names Incorrect"
then return to beginning. else continue

Find a number that is not in the ID Column then Declare as @Number

```
Declare @NewID AS int
Declare @OldID AS int

SET @NewID = ID Where Name = New.Name
SET @OldID = ID where Name = Old.Name

UPDATE Table SET ID = @Number WHERE ID = @NewID
UPDATE Table SET ID = @NewID WHERE ID = @OldID
UPDATE Table SET ID = @OldID WHERE ID =  @NewID
```

Is it possible to code this in SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services?

I have tried my best with my little knowledge of SQL but I am not sure what to do with the rest.

Comment: And what does "number in = 0" mean? I have no idea what you want to do or know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I think this is possible.

SQL Server Reporting Services accepts parameters and can pass these to a stored procedure.

These parameters can also be bound to lists which means that the `NewName` and `OldName` parameters could be populated with existing values from the `Name` column.

The stored procedure would need to return a result set (say with one column called `result` that you then display on the report)

This isn't a typical use for SSRS though and may well not be the best interface for doing this.

Comment: What would be best for this sort of thing.